# Does Couchbase spread high use keys across cluster

Tags: caching, couchbase, key-value-store

We are using Couchbase 4.0 as a key/value cache layer on a cluster of web nodes and have 1 key that gets a very high number of requests because it is accessed by almost every web request.  *I know that this key should be stored local to each box, that is something we are addressing and is not the target of this question*

In the couchbase admin we can see that it is doing 6000k ops/sec.  It is not being written to very frequently and we have 1 replica so most of these are gets.  We will see 1 node's get/sec metric increase linearly over the course of the day up to approximately 1k gets/sec then drop down to the rest over the course of a single period without the increase of other servers gets/sec metric.  This is all very unusual per my understanding of how Couchbase (and other key/value stores) work.  If *feels* like couchbase is distributing the key across multiple nodes but I cannot find any documentation that says it makes replicas for anything other than backups.  Thoughts?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you're reading the docs correctly.  Couchbase does not distribute KV copies to load balance.  This would cause potential consistency problems, so you wouldn't want to do that without the user knowing.

You can explicitly read from a replica.  You can read about that here: http://developer.couchbase.com/documentation/server/current/sdk/java/document-operations.html

It mentions some of the circumstances where you might want to do this and trade-offs for doing so.